# Why does NLTK tag "there" as "Determiner" when using the universal tagset?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

When using the universal tagset with NLTK, it identifies "There" as a determiner, but it does not make sense. For example,

```
import nltk 
from nltk import word_tokenize

sentence = 'If there is a cat under the table' 
tokens = word_tokenize(sentence) 
tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens, tagset='universal')
```

The output is:

```
[('If', 'ADP'), ('there', 'DET'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('a', 'DET'), ('cat', 'NOUN'), ('under', 'ADP'), ('the', 'DET'), ('table', 'NOUN')]
```

The second word is "there", and is tagged a 'DET', but it should just be a pronoun. Is it a problem of the NLTK pos tagger, or is that I am misunderstanding the tag?

(Note: if we use the default tagset, it correctly identifies "there" as an "existencial there", or, "EX").

Answer (score 0):

In the [mapping from the Penn Treebank tagset to the Universal Tagset](https://github.com/slavpetrov/universal-pos-tags/blob/master/en-ptb.map), `EX` is mapped to `DET`, so it's all working as expected. It is debatable whether the mapping is accurate enough, but with only 12 available tags it is probably not possible to get everything perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the mapping. However, I still find weird that EX is mapped to DET: "there" can never be a determiner, it's not a matter that depends on the sentence.

Comment: @sgduran91 Agreed. But it's a weird one, so I guess it had to go somewhere...